# How to show SSRS URL Report in Print Preview Mode?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, print-preview

I am showing report from web (angular application) through SSRS URL. It shows me output like below. 
[image]

How can i show report default as print preview mode? In PDF its showing correctly but i want same view in browser.

Thanks.!!

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of any option to do this. You can schedule this report to generate the PDF to a physical location and have your customers access the PDF directly if you want to hide the SSRS interface... but a lot of people like to export tables like this to Excel.

I recommend you educate your customers how to use this interface as it is pretty useful.

Comment: Yes dear friend in PDF i am aware its possible but looking for solution on browser view.

Comment: You can export to XHTML and link to it that way too. These are "Paginated Reports" and that is a paginated view above. There is no print preview option on the controls so I don't expect there is anyway to trigger that in the URL.